# extract indexes corresponding to the range of nested list elements

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
```

I'm trying to extract the rows with indexes that correspond to the range given in a nested list:

```
a = [[2,4],[6,7]]
```

Basically, I need to find a way to expand `a` to this:

```
df.loc[[2,3,4, 6,7]]
```

Is there a neat way to do this in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you're searching for [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html#pandas-cut):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})
a = [[2, 4], [6, 7]]

bins = pd.cut(
    df["x"], bins=pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(list(map(tuple, a)), closed="both")
)

print(df.loc[pd.notna(bins), "x"])
```

Prints:

```
2    2
3    3
4    4
6    6
7    7
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

We can loop over each range in `a` then use `range()` to loop through each number in that range and add each to an output list (named `b`).

```py
>>> a = [[2,4],[6,7]]
>>> b = []
... for low, high in a:
...   for number in range(low, high + 1): # add one because your range is inclusive
...     b.append(number)
...
>>> b
[2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```

Or, as a more compact list comprehension:

```py
>>> a = [[2,4],[6,7]]
>>> b = [number for start, stop in a for number in range(start, stop + 1)]
>>> b
[2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```

Of course, you can now provide `b` to `df.loc[b]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could `sum` a list of ranges generated from `a`:

```py
a = [[2,4],[6,7]]

rng = sum((list(range(v[0], v[1]+1)) for v in a), [])
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```

And then use that to index into your dataframe:

```
df.loc[rng]
```

Output:

```
   x
2  2
3  3
4  4
6  6
7  7
```